# Color bar legend for kernel2d function

Tags: r, spatial, kernel-density, spatstat

I've used the `spatstat` package and the `kernel2d()` function to make a kernel density map of point data for disease cases in the DRC

```
kern <- kernel2d(pts, ply, bdw, kernel='quartic')
# plot
plot(ProvinceBorders)
image(kern, add=TRUE)
```

How do I get a color bar legend?  I know `kern$z` will have my values so I can find the max and min and I know folks like `colorRampPalette()`and stuff like that but I quite like these default colors and I'm not even sure how many color "buckets" they are sorted into, which a lot of the DIY and `RcolorBrewer` solutions require.

thanks!
[image: map]

Answer (score 0):

If you really use `spatstat` as you write, you could do something like:

```r
library(spatstat)
X <- as.ppp(pts, W = ply) ## Requires pts is a data.frame with coords, and ply is an owin object
kern <- density(X, sigma = bdw, kernel='quartic') # Require bdw to be given as a number
# plot
plot(kern) # Automatic color scale
plot(ProvinceBorders, add=TRUE) # Requires ProvinceBorders to be a tess object
```

Comment: oh yeah oops `kernel2d` is in the `splancs` package... I guess I need to look under the hood and see if they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

`kernel2d` is a function in the `splancs` package. It is not compatible with `spatstat`.

The analogous function in the `spatstat` package that calculates a kernel estimate of intensity is `density.ppp`, a method for the generic function `density`.

The result of `density.ppp` is a pixel image (class `im`) which can be plotted immediately using `plot.im`, a method for the generic `plot`. By default, the output of `plot.im` includes a colour scale at the right hand side of the image. You can read the online help for `plot.im` to understand how to control this.
It should not be necessary to extract pixel values, calculate the range of values, etc.